# Reclassification of raster surface using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.2, dem, classification, reclassify

I have a raster surface with values ranging from 0 -100. I want to create a categorical classification (percentage categories of 5%, e.g. 0-5%, 6-10%...) and reclassify my surface into these categories. I am not sure exactly how to do this. I was wondering whether anyone could guide me through the steps I need to take. I am not sure whether I need to start in the Layer properties>Symbology before using the reclassify tool and if so what exactly do I need to choose in terms of the classification (e.g. natural, equal Interval etc.) and that sort of thing. I read the online help pages but I am still not getting anywhere!

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I would use the reclassify tool. Set it to twenty 'equal interval' breaks of 5 each.

2) Then use the raster (created in step 1) for rendering. Bring it into ArcGIS and select 20 classes.

You could certainly skip step one but it may be nice to have this layer if you plan to use it in future analysis.

You could also just do 2 and save as a layer file and open the layer file each time.

Really it depends if you want to do future analysis then use 1 and 2. If you just want to view then use only step 2.